# Why is parse method throwing a type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' error?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a very simple method that converts a dynamic variable to an int like so:

```
  int _convertedNum(dynamic number){
    int intNumber = int.parse(number);

    return intNumber;
  }
```

I have this model class:

```
class Properties {

    dynamic popEst;


    dynamic confirmed;

    Properties({

        this.popEst,

        this.confirmed
    });

    factory Properties.fromJson(String str) => Properties.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Properties.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Properties(

        popEst: json["pop_est"],

        confirmed: json["confirmed"]
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {

        "pop_est": popEst,

        "confirmed": confirmed
    };
}
```

Now when I try using the method to convert the properties from the class above from dynamic to int:

```
_convertedNum(properties.popEst);
```

I get **type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'** error. I tried changing the properties from dynamic to String, still same error.

I also tried doing this to the json:

```
confirmed: json["confirmed"].toInt();
```

Throwing similar error too.

How do I convert the properties to integers please?.

Comment: Are the properties numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe some of your properties are already integers. Since `int.parse()` want a `String` as parameter, maybe doing:

```dart
int _convertedNum(dynamic number){
  int intNumber = int.parse(number.toString());

  return intNumber;
}
```

Can solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah!...It did actually!. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because `parse`, as it's documentation say, takes a source which is `String` and converts it to an `int`, while what you are doing (from the error) is passing bare `int`s to `parse`,

solution:

```
int func(dynmaic number){
    int intNumber = int.parse(number.toString());

    return intNumber;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Your explanation is top notch!, and completely clarifies my confusion!

Comment: just a suggestion, specify types else than dynamic or put an assert statement if you want to keep dynamic in order to avoid these errors before the app goes to production

Comment: Ok. I'll definitely do that!. Thanks Once again.

Answer (score 0):

The data you're passing is of type integer. You can try to check the data type like this:

```
if(number is int){ 

}
```